# .htaccess pagination redirect rule

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I have a website with a pagination its link as the following:

```
page 1 url = domain.com/abcd.html/
page 2 url = domain.com/abcd/index2.html
page 3 url = domain.com/abcd/index3.html
```

Can all links in the website be redirected from:

```
page 1 url = domain.com/abcd.html/  == To page 1 url = domain.com/abcd.html/
page 2 url = domain.com/abcd/index2.html == To page 2 url = domain.com/abcd.html?pg=2
page 3 url = domain.com/abcd/index3.html == To page 3 url = domain.com/abcd.html?pg=3
```

using an .htaccess rule?

abcd is a dynamic categories name its have many of them and its only example for one category... what I'm looking for to make all dynamic categories to be redirected using only one line.

Thank you,
Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^/]+)/index([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html?pg=%2 [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your support == do I need to change the THE_REQUEST to the category_name? this will be static... or just use it as it is?

Comment: The rule I posted accepts urls with dynmic leading paths so you dont need to change it

Comment: Working perfect :) Thank you for this great efforts.

Comment: this code is working perfect... but there is an issue I need your help to fix it please :) ... if the link look like this: **domain.com/category_name/index2.html** its working fine as it will be redirect to **domain.com/category_name.html?pg=2** == BUT if the link will look like this **domain.com/parent_category/category_name/index2.html** ==  problem will start as the result will be **domain.com/category_name.html?pg=2**   which will lead to 404 page as the correct link should be **domain.com/parent_category/category_name/index2.html?pg=2**

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^index(\d+)\.html$  index.html?pg=$1 [NC,L]
```

rewrite  `index3.html` to `index.html?pg=3` without url change

Comment: I'm sorry for changing my comment...the paging url will be some thing like this abcd.html/ and when I click the second page it will change to be like this: abcd/index2.html == how can I force it redirect to abcd.html?pg=2 , thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming abcd is not a folder, to get the webpages like that you need this code

For the one is default abcd.html I think you don't need anything, because it redirect to the same page

Real address: domain.com/category_name/index2.html
Rewrite address: domain.com/category_name.html?pg=2 (the one the users get it)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html?pg=(.*)$ ./$1/index$2.html
```

Comment: Thank you for youe support...(abcd) is a category name which is something dynamic...is there any way to make it all in one line as I have more then 100 categories?

Comment: @TariqAhmed I just modify my answer

Comment: Thank you again, the result is 404 page not found...I used only the last code you provided...would you please advise? Thank you

Comment: Which web do you try? do you try domain.com/abcd.html/? try eliminating the last /

Comment: example for a link is domain.com/category_name/index2.html ==> this is page number two == I want it to be domain.com/category_name.html?pg=2

Comment: Which address is the real one, the one right now you can access? and which one is the one you can to be the new "pretty url"

Comment: Its already fixed with the code provided by @Starkeen, Thank you so much foryour efforts brother :)